# Coldfusion's SerializeJSON does not get along with MS SQL 2008

Tags: json, sql-server-2008, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm on Adobe Coldfusion 9.0.1 and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 and confirm the following on 2008 Express. I have two tables which I JOIN and serialize the result to a JavaScript Variable using Coldfusion's own SerializeJson function.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[event](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[date1] [date] NULL,
[date2] [datetime] NULL,
[date3] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[status] [nchar](10) NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[status](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[text] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
);
```

My first CFQuery looks like

```
<cfquery name="qryprod" datasource="mssqlexpress">
    SELECT  e.id, date1, date2, date3
    FROM    event e
    inner join  status s
    on  e.status = s.id
    WHERE   e.id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="2">
</cfquery>
#SerializeJson( qryprod, true )#
```

All three dates are serialized to something like: `Februar, 27 2012 22:10:12` - Monthnames in German.

My second Query:

```
<cfquery name="qryprod" datasource="mssqlexpress">
    WITH subStatus AS (
        SELECt  id, text
        FROM    status
    )
    SELECT  e.id, date1, date2, date3
    FROM    event e
    inner join  subStatus s
    on      e.status = s.id
    WHERE   e.id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="2">
</cfquery>
#SerializeJson( qryprod, true )#
```

- date1 of type `date` is serialized to `2012-02-27`
- date2 of type `datetime`is serialized to `Februar, 27 2012 22:10:12`
- date3 of type `datetime2` looks like `2012-02-27 22:10:12.4400000`

How does that happen and what do I have to do to always get my dates in the form `Monthname, day year`?

Best,
Bernhard

Comment: You might be able to figure out why this is happening by looking at the resultSetMetaData, and pulling up the column types returned to coldfusion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Someone in real life advised to check the JDBC driver. Microsoft provides information they fixed something with `date`, `datetime2` and `DATETIMEOFFSET` in a current update: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=28562 I used this driver instead of the one provided with Coldfusion and it worked as I originally expected.

Comment: The JDBC driver provided with the beta of Coldfsuin 10 delivers the expected results. Just tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to loop through the query result, and change the date values to strings manually. You can use [`ParseDateTime`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7843.html) and [`DateFormat`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ff4.html) (or their localized versions, [`LSParseDateTime`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-70e3.html) and [`LSDateFormat`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6de1.html)) to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used getMetadate.getColumntype on the CFQUERY-Result. For the dates returned in the wrong format it returned varchar, for the working ones datetime.

Comment: @Bardware Why are you using three different representations for dates in the database? Why not settle on just one?

Comment: I used the three representation to show the differences. In my 2008 R" database all my date-columns are of type `datetime2`. I noticed datetime2 is serialized wrongly and wanted to see how it works with the other types.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the T-SQL CONVERT function.

```
SELECT  e.id, CONVERT(varchar(15), date1, 107) AS date1...
```

The above format code will return mon dd, yyyy format.

If you want the full month name, you can use date functions:

```
SELECT  e.id, 
(
DATENAME(month, date1) + ' ' + 
CAST(DATEPART(d, date1) AS varchar(2)) + ', ' + 
CAST(DATEPART(yyyy, date1) AS varchar(4))
) AS date1
...
```